# How do I remove an extra recovery partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, disk-management, mbr

I had an IT person at my company clone my SSD (the old one had failing sectors). When he did so I ended up with 2 recovery partitions, and the second one stops me from making my C: drive larger. I'm also guessing the second partition is of no use.

[image]

Can I just delete the 2nd recovery partition? If not, what should I do?

Also, is there anything I need to do to make sure the primary recovery partition is up to date?

thanks - dave

Comment: From the listing it appears that disc 1 partition 3 is empty, so It's unlikely to be of much use: mount it to verify that it has no files. Note that this is not the same as disc 1 partition 1, which probably contains boot files and no recovery data (again mount to verify). If disc 1 partition 3 is indeed empty, then you will lose nothing by deleting it. Any recovery will need to be done with an install disc.

Answer (score 0):

From the disk layout, it looks like the old SSD is 500GB and the new SSD is 1TB.

To exactly expand c: is not possible without removing / relocating the recovery partition. The problem is, It may not work if you pressed F8 later to access some advanced boot menu options. Fyi my MSI laptop using F8, perhaps your laptop using different shortcuts.

you need to "rearrange the layout" using recovery disk. then you will have a big C drive in the middle.

Comment: How do I rearrange the layout using the recovery disk? thanks

Comment: recovery disk comes with branded laptop. What is your laptop brand ?

Comment: It's a desktop, a Dell Optiplex 790.

Comment: Here are the links for your optiflex:

https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-General/Creating-Restore-Disc-Windows-7-Pro-With-an-Optiplex-790/m-p/4066547

http://www.dell.com/support/article/my/en/mydhs1/sln301133/windows-7-recovery-image-download-available-with-usb-31-and-nvme-driver-support?lang=en

http://www.dell.com/support/article/my/en/mydhs1/sln130027/factory-reset-restore-or-reinstall-microsoft-windows-on-a-dell-computer?lang=en

You need  your service tag number to download recovery disks.

Recovery disks usually comes in 4 -6 DVD images.